# loop through access form and print each value in msgbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form based on myquery that looks like this:

### name   color

```
tom    red
mike   blue
joe    red
```

Say I want to click a button and have a msgbox appear with the text "tom", then immediately upon closing that text box another appears with "mike" and closing again will show the last msgbox "joe", is there a way to do this with a loop? I found a similar question on stackoverflow but that code only produced the first record, "tom" three times. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the code wasn't actually moving to the next record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a button on the form.

In the `On Click` event on the Event Tab in the Properties window of the button, I used this code:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

Do While Not rs.EOF Or rs.BOF
    MsgBox rs!name
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

This makes a clone of the Recordset behind the form, and iterates through each of the records, displaying what you asked for.

To Wayne's credit, I was a little surprised we didn't have to change `rs!name` to `rs![name]` because it's a reserved word. And he's right - you should *stay away* from using them as field (column) names.

Comment: this did not work for me. so i open the form based on myquery, for the onclick event of the button i put that code and just swapped the command6_click() for my button which is command44_click(), and swapped the name for my actual field name msgbox rs!firstname. A msgbox did appear with the first name on the first record, i clicked ok and another msgbox appear for a total of 3 msgbox's, equal to my 3 records. the problem is the value of the field is not changing (it just shows tom 3 times)

Comment: ahhhhhhhh my mistake! the form is based on a TABLE, does this change anything? it is not a query

Comment: very close. I had to add rs.movefirst before the do while not loop. All i need now is to only run the msgbox if color = red and i'm all set!

Comment: Hm.. Sometimes that code is required, (honestly, I'm not 100% sure why.) but `.MoveLast` then `.MoveFirst` is sometimes used to populate the recordset. Depends on how you set things up. If you are unsure how to do what you are asking, post a new question. I suggest giving it an attempt first, though!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already opened your recordset, the following will work:

```
Do While Not MyRS.EOF
    Msgbox MyRS!MyName    'Note I changed your field name because you are asking for major trouble by using reserved words for field names!
    MyRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: This did not work for me either. I made a mistake and the form is actually based on a TABLE. I tried this code as well and approached the same problem.

Comment: Then please explain exactly what action you want to take to start the loop, and what determines if you display a message. A table has rows and columns. Does this mean that if you click on row 3, column 2, then you want to display everything in the same column, or same row; starting at the first row or column or from where you clicked?

Comment: i figured it out, i needed a rs.movefirst before the loop :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I finally got working, i just had to add one line to fix it.

```
dim rs as dao.recordsetclone  
rs.movefirst  
do while not rs.eof  
if rs!color='red' then  
msgbox rs!stuff  
end if  
rs.movenext  
loop  
set rs=nothing  
end sub
```